# Unity IAP log message

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am using Unity IAP in my game and google play billing service for selling some item.

Now when I run in unity Editor, everything works as expected. No issues what so ever in the editor. But when I run on an android device, below message come

`03-28 03:47:36.519 2829-2844/? I/UnityIAP: Expected to find a single Google Play billing service but found 0`

As expected, no popup message comes from UnityIAP to purchase an item.
I googled about this behavior but didn't find any relevant document.

It would be really helpful if someone can help me understand this message or point me to a link when this behavior is explained

Comment: The version you're testing is an alpha or beta that you uploaded to the store?

Comment: Does this mean that I can only test this when I actually publish my game ?

Comment: Well you can publish an alpha which no one else then the testers that you've set up will see. And yeah they will never work by just building it on your phone.